# Record information from the SQL generated by Linq-to-sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

From each sql sentence generated (and executed successful) by linq I need know the following information:

- the real sql sentece with parameter values
- start date of execution
- end date of execution
- the number of records returned (if is a select)

Anyone know how to get this information?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the generated SQL query from the [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx) property of your data context:
Example would be:

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

foreach(Customer custObj in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(custObj.CustomerID);
}
```

For start and end of execution I don't hink that you could do that with linq specifically. You can use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to measure the time but that would also calculate the time the .NET runtime needs to generate the SQL from the expression tree from the IQueryable interface that your linq to sql statement presents.

In plain SQL there are several ways you can get the time of execution for a query:

- using SQL server profiler
- using a SQL Script with `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` parameters

  ```
  DECLARE @StartTime datetime,@EndTime datetime    
  SELECT @StartTime=GETDATE()    
  -- your query    
  SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()    
  SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in microseconds]
  ```
- using a SQL Script with SET STATISTICS TIME (Transact-SQL)

  ```
  SET STATISTICS TIME ON
  GO  
  -- your query  
  SET STATISTICS TIME OFF  
  GO
  ```

As for the number of affected rows you can also try several approaches. You can:

- try DataContext.GetChangeSet, this should return the update count
  with:

  ```
  dataContext.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count
  ```
- try to return `@@ROWCOUNT`
- if you have multiple updates you can try to return them as output
  parameters from a stored procedure

Comment: ...or use a profiler built specifically for using with Linq-to-SQL: http://huagati.com/L2Sprofiler/

Comment: @KristoferA-Huagati.com Looks like a very nice tool. I myself will definetly give it a try ;) The answer is driven by the fact that I somehow understood that he want's to retrieve all these values programatically.